# ¿Existe alguna manera de recibir notificaciones a las etiquetas que sigo?

Tags: discusión

Últimamente me he interesado por ser parte de esta linda comunidad y contribuir con mis poco conocimientos acerca de programación a otras personas. Razón por lo cual he hecho seguimiento a varias etiquetas de mi interés como por ejemplo: `Python, Numpy, Pandas, etc.`

Por lo que me preguntaba si había alguna manera de recibir notificaciones de dichas etiquetas cuando se publique una nueva pregunta o cuando se responda alguna pregunta de mi interés.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si te refieres a notificaciones por correo, en principio si es posible recibirlas, aunque yo nunca lo he probado asi que no puedo confirmarlo al 100%.

Para ello, debes crear un filtro, en [Filtros](https://stackexchange.com/filters/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí configuras las etiquetas que quieres seguir, el sitio (en este caso Stack Overflow en español) y la ultima opción te permite recibir notificaciones al correo que especifiques y con la periodicidad que quieras.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Probaré la opción.